# Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined - ^^c0

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I have a very large LaTeX document which can't be compiled because of following error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty:1398:
Package inputenc Er
ror: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1398 \ifcat ^^c0
                  \active \pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

The problem is, I'm not able to find the problematic symbol, because of the document's size.

I wanted to "replace" the character with something different like this

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{^^c0}{?????}
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or this character simply can't be replaced? Or do you have any other tip how to find the mistake?

I'm using `pdflatex`.

I've read several other questions, but I've not been able to solve this anyway:

- [package inputenc error : the keyboard character used is undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236826/package-inputenc-error-the-keyboard-character-used-is-undefined)
- [æ ø å giving "Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193679/%C3%A6-%C3%B8-%C3%A5-giving-package-inputenc-error-keyboard-character-used-is-undefined)
- [Unicode characters in pdflatex output using hexcode without UTF-8 input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89796/unicode-characters-in-pdflatex-output-using-hexcode-without-utf-8-input)

---

#### EDIT

It's [this document](https://www.overleaf.com/6041049cgzbms#/20141246/) - I've deleted almost all the text in `main.tex` and it's still not working...

---

#### EDIT 2

Ok, the problem is obviously caused by `pdfx` package. I've tried to move it before `inputenc` include like this

```
\RequirePackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\RequirePackage[latin1, utf8]{inputenc},
```

but now it gives me another error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls:235:
LaTeX Error: Comm
and \maketitle already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.235 }
```

Comment: It's on line 1398.

Comment: @cfr The problem is, document is structured like a lot of small .tex files, so I don't know, which line is it really.

Comment: Then comment stuff out until you find it, I guess. Sometimes, you can `grep` them, but not always.

Comment: I guess `pdfx` should be loaded before `inputenc`, but the class does the converse.

Comment: @egreg `pdfx` is the problem, but it didn't solve it completely. I've added info to my question.

Comment: @Eenoku Sorry, but the class is very ill-written. `pdfx` and `inputenc` should be loaded after `\LoadClass`. Actually, just moving the `\LoadClass` line before the first `\RequirePackage` should do.

Comment: @egreg Great, that works! Could you, please, rewrite your advice as an answer, so I could accept it? And include the specific lines from the class, please. I think it will make the answer more useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class file `diploma.cls` is not well written.

Packages should generally be loaded after `\LoadClass`. You can just move the `\LoadClass` declaration at the top. Also `pdfx` should be loaded before `inputenc`.

```
\def\fileversion{9.0}
\def\filedate{2016/06/20}
\def\docdate{20. června 2016}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{diploma}[\filedate\space \fileversion\space diploma EXPERIMENTAL LaTeX document class]
\LoadClass[11pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\RequirePackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
```

I don't think the `latin1` option to `inputenc` does anything good. Actually, the package should be loaded in the document and not by the class.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes is just an copy-paste issue.

Try manually re-writting the problem line.

It happened to me once that I helped a student who had some syntax error on a python line, the line visibly was something like:

```
variable = [1,2,3].append("text")
```

then I decided to delete that line, character by character, and it turned out that between the `=` and the `[` characters I  had to press 5 times the backspace.

This usually happens when you copy something from a rendered text document, like a PDF file, to your console.

Answer (score 0):

People will tell you not to do it but just delete all root_document.bbl, root_document.out, etc. files (presuming root_document is, well, you root document). Often these files don't update properly even after you removed the problematic character. Just recompile and things will be fine.